# Google user info gives only id by access token from android google plus

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-plus, access-token

I use Google Plus sdk to login. If is succces, i request the user's access token

```
String scope = "oauth2:" + Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN + " " + Scopes.PLUS_PROFILE;
String token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(context, mPlusClient.getAccountName(), scope);
```

It works and i get the token, but the when i try it (i will send to a server the token) i got this:

https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=ya29.xxx...

```
{ id: "1060xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" }
```

Where is the other data for example e-mail, name etc???

I tried another soution and i added server part to scope:

```
String CLIENT_ID = "abc123.apps.googleusercontent.com";
List<String> SCOPES = Arrays.asList(new String[]{
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me"
});

String scope = String.format("oauth2:server:client_id:%s:api_scope:%s", CLIENT_ID, TextUtils.join(" ", SCOPES));
```

but in this case i always get error:

```
com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: Unknown
    at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1):

The full set of Google+ scopes is documented here: https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth#scopes

You can also use the OAuth Playground: https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/ to explore the scopes used by other Google services

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem and the problem were the scopes. The adnroid documentation define only 5 scopes:
http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/Scopes.html

```
String  APP_STATE   Scope for using the App State service.
String  DRIVE_FILE  Scopes for access user-authorized files from Google Drive.
String  GAMES   Scope for accessing data from Google Play Games.
String  PLUS_LOGIN  OAuth 2.0 scope for accessing the user's name, basic profile info, list of people in the user's circles, and writing app activities to Google.
String  PLUS_PROFILE    OAuth 2.0 scope for accessing the user's Google+ profile data.
```

but there are some others for exmaple:

```
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read",
```

and when i added them the user info request gaved other data too.